# How to ensure the triggered jobs are rescheduled after the AppDomain recycle in Kudu, or to make an http request on recycles

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8.5, kudu

We are using [Kudu](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu) as a standalone installation, to manage all the IIS applications. But after the AppDomain or AppPool get recycled, all triggered jobs are rescheduled only after the next http request. The AppPool has been configured as "AlwaysRunning", and also "Preload" was enabled for the sites.

As possible workaround I can imagine, to fire an http request on AppDomain/Pool recycle, but how this can be achieved on IIS Configuration level, without modifying the Kudu sources?

Thank you.

Comment: Hello @davidebbo, may I politely invite you to the thread? Would you have any ideas how to enforce jobs rescheduling after AppDomain/AppPool recycle? Thank you. _As it is an IIS subject, I haven't opened any issues on gitbhub_